# Is the story about Cauchy and Stupnitsky true or fictional?

Tags: math-history

It was told in "21" movie that Cauchy was accused by his student Vladimir Stupnitsky that Cauchy stole his equation. But I googled nothing about such a person.

Is this story fictional or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a transcript of the film, Rosa first mentions Vladimir Stupnitsky as Ben's disguise. He later uses the pseudonym to send a code to Ben to define their (non) relationship. So, no, Rosa made the story up, using names only the blackjack group could understand to send a message to Ben.

21 Script on Script O Rama
http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/t/21-script-transcript.html